# using OpenCV in VS code

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-code, mingw

I'm writing a simple program using VS Code, Mingw and OpenCv Lib. I downloaded a prebuild OpenCV package from [here](https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build) and I followed the instruction in this [page](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/vs-code-with-opencv-c-on-windows-10-explained-256418442c52) for building the code. I can build the program successfully with no error but there is a problem. when I call OpenCV function(like `cv::imread`) an segmentation fault occurs. It will be appreciated for any kind of help.

task.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/utils.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-IC:\\OpenCV\\include",
                "-LC:\\OpenCV\\x64\\mingw\\bin",
                "-llibopencv_calib3d341",
                "-llibopencv_core341",
                "-llibopencv_dnn341",
                "-llibopencv_features2d341",
                "-llibopencv_flann341",
                "-llibopencv_highgui341",
                "-llibopencv_imgcodecs341",
                "-llibopencv_imgproc341",
                "-llibopencv_ml341",
                "-llibopencv_objdetect341",
                "-llibopencv_photo341",
                "-llibopencv_shape341",
                "-llibopencv_stitching341",
                "-llibopencv_superres341",
                "-llibopencv_video341",
                "-llibopencv_videoio341",
                "-llibopencv_videostab341"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:/OpenCV/include/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
        "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this on Windows? If so I don't think the issue is with your VS Code files if you're only facing problems after build. You may want to check your opencv or mingw-w64 installation, did you build and install with cmake? For Mingw64, was your install configuration correct for your machine?

Assuming of course that everything has also been added to your Windows path environment variable, I tested your `cpp_properties.json` and `tasks.json` setup with my own opencv windows vs code environment. The only things I did differently were to get rid of include errors, such as:

```
        "problemMatcher": {
            "base": "$gcc",
            "fileLocation": [
                "absolute"
            ]
        },
        "group": {
            "kind":"build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
```

To my `tasks.json problemMatcher` statement and `group` statement so that the system could properly find the opencv library. I also don't know what the `"${workspaceFolder}/utils.cpp"` line is doing in `tasks.json`, but regardless, if you're able to build fine it would seem to me there's more likely an underlying problem with either mingw or opencv.